# How to receive money on PayPal without PayPal sending a confirmation email with my name in it?

Tags: paypal

I don't want the confirmation email that the payor gets to include my name. How can I avoid that?

My name and email address also show up in the email underneath the word "Merchant".

Is there a way to change these things?

Comment: Someone suggested changing to a new email address, but now that answer is gone. Is that not a valid solution?

Comment: Probably/possibly not, except perhaps by creating a business account... see [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/43183/35567).

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for people not to see your email. They have to know where the money comes from. If you don't want them to see your real name, you can change your name on PayPal and enter anything else there.